# Read analog button values from PS3 controller on OS X

Tags: osx-yosemite, iokit, playstation3

So I am playing with IOKit and getting input from my PS3 controller. It works and I can read the state of every button and both sticks. Sort of. I only get an integer value of 0 or 1 from the triggers and the dpad. When I test the controller on http://html5gamepad.com/ I see a float value from 0-1 on both. Does anybody know how to get the analog values?

My input value callback looks like:

```
inputCallback(void * context, IOReturn result, void * sender, IOHIDValueRef valueRef)
{
    if (IOHIDValueGetLength(valueRef) > 2) {
        return;
    }

    IOHIDElementRef element = IOHIDValueGetElement(valueRef);

    if (CFGetTypeID(element) != IOHIDElementGetTypeID()) {
        return;
    }

    int usagePage = IOHIDElementGetUsagePage(element);
    int usage = IOHIDElementGetUsage(element);
    CFIndex value = IOHIDValueGetIntegerValue(valueRef);

    switch (usagePage)
    ...
```

I am on OS X 10.10.

Thanks

Comment: Just stating the obvious. what does IOHIDValueGetScaledValue(valueRef, kIOHIDValueScaleTypeCalibrated) give you?

Comment: So this has been a long time. `IOHIDValueGetScaledValue(valueRef, kIOHIDValueScaleTypeCalibrated)` gives me `0.0` always. `IOHIDValueGetScaledValue(ValueRef, kIOHIDValueScaleTypePhysical)` gives me `1.0` on down and `0.0` on up. I may be lacking some configuration?